# How to add the facebook pixel code script in particular category page?

Tags: facebook

I am trying to add facebook pixel code in particular category.How can i add that js file in magento please help me.

Comment: please mention your magento version and come more detail your questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) create a template file with you FB pixel code and put it into

**app/design/frontend/THEME/PACKAGE/template/your_file.phtml**

2.) add a block to layout with your modules layout.xml or local.xml in

**app/design/frontend/THEME/PACKAGE/layout/**

```
<CATEGORY_{id}>
    <reference name="before_body_end">
        <block type="core/template" name="fb.pixel">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>your_file.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</CATEGORY_{id}>
```

Or

You can do the same from backend ... **"Admin - Catalog - Manage Categories"** and paste code from above (without `<CATEGORY_{id}>`) into categories **"Custom Layout Update"** section.

---

<sup>See your other questions belongs to Magento2 ... this is for M1, but it should work similiar there.</sup>